# Dependency exports an empty object when bundling component library with Rollup

Tags: rollupjs

I'm trying to use rollup to build my React component library. The bundle step completes with a few warnings, however, when I actually try to use it in a Next.js application, I get many "X is not a function" errors when visiting the website. It seems to happen because some dependencies inside the `_virtual` directory are empty:

For example, this is `dist/_virtual/d3-time-format.js` (my library uses `@visx/scale`, which depends on `d3-scale`, which in turn depends on `d3-time-format`)

```js
var d3TimeFormat = {exports: {}};

export { d3TimeFormat as d };
//# sourceMappingURL=d3-time-format.js.map
```

As you can see above, the `exports` is an empty object, so I get the error "format is not a function". This happens also with other modules, like `prop-types` (my dependencies depend on it).

This is my rollup.config.js:

```js
import { babel } from '@rollup/plugin-babel';
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs';
import resolve from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';
import typescript from '@rollup/plugin-typescript';
import svgr from '@svgr/rollup';
import peerDepsExternal from 'rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external';

function bundle(inputPath) {
  return {
    input: inputPath,
    output: [
      {
        dir: `./dist`,
        format: 'esm',
        sourcemap: true,
        preserveModules: true,
        preserveModulesRoot: 'src',
      },
    ],
    plugins: [
      peerDepsExternal(),
      commonjs(),
      resolve(),
      svgr({
        icon: true,
        replaceAttrValues: { '#000': '{props.color}' },
        svgProps: { fill: 'currentColor' },
      }),
      typescript(),
      babel({
        babelHelpers: 'runtime',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        extensions: ['.js', '.ts', '.tsx'],
      }),
    ],
  };
}

export default [bundle('./src/index.ts')];
```

When bundling I get these warnings, not sure if they are relevant:

[image: Warning shown when bundling]

Would appreciate some guidance on what the files inside _virtual are and why they are generated with an empty object. Thanks@